# Pass active class into dropdown

Tags: matrix, navigation

I have a dynamic navigation consisting out of matrix and entries fields:

[image]

This then gets printed on the frontend as a dropdown.

No is it somehow possible to add a active class to the dropdown toplevel button?

Basicaly passing the active state back up to the toplevel button.

```
{% for dropNavi in block.dropdownNavi %}
   {% if loop.first %}
      <li class="dropdown {# that's where the class should end up #}">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
           {{ block.seite }} <span class="caret"></span>
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   {% endif %}
   <li {# here adding an active class is easy #}>
    <a href="{{ dropNavi.url }}">{{ dropNavi.title }}</a>
   </li>
  {% if loop.last %}</ul>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that this is a matrix field so there could be 3 or 6 or 5 dropdowns. Therefore the `{{ loop.index }}` does not work as a identifier. I can't see a way. Is this even possible?

I tried things like `<li class="dropdown {% if craft.request.getLastSegement == dropNavi.url %}">` and various versions of this.

But stuff like this aplies an active class to all the dropdowns present. Never on the one containing the current url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heck! I just did it with jQuery:

```
$('.nav .dropdown-menu li.active').parents('li').addClass('activeParent');​
```

and that's that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="{{ page.getUrl }}" {{craft.request.getSegment(2)|lower==page.slug|lower ? 'class=is-active'|e : ''}}>
    {{ page.title}}
</a>
```

You can use something like this, only you compare your `getSegment()` with the related Title field instead of `page.slug` if your page in your url has the pagetitle name.

Comment: Unfortunately slug and pagetitle are not the same